# 403 Error: access_denied, Error_description: Invalid client for this origin

Tags: angular, azure, google-authentication, angular-social-login

Angular v12 using `angularx-social-login` for Google Authentication, works out OK at local. Deploy to Azure as App Service, copy the URL paste into Google Cloud's `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs` in addition to existing `localhost:4200`.

Client ID is hardcoded into app.module.ts below, and verified system variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is not matter.

```
providers: 
  [
    {
        provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
        useValue:
        {
            autoLogin: false,
            providers: 
            [
                {
                    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider('xyz123.apps.googleusercontent.com') 
                }
            ]
        } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    },
    ...
  ],
```

After entering account and password get 403

```
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Invalid client for this origin."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround could be help to resolve the above issue:

Looking at your code it seems you have provided the `uri` instead of `CLIENT ID`

***Please make sure to Add the clientID for the application that you have deployed in Azure*** .

To get the ClientID of application:
***AAD>APP REGISTRATION>CREATE NEW(IF NOT)> OVERVIEW***

EXAMPLE OF SAMPLE CODE:-

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'clientId'
            )
          },
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***ANGULAR SOCIAL LOGIN| NPMJS***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login)
- BLOG: [***Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications***](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps)